# c++ - string confrontation issue

Tags: c++, arrays, string, if-statement, getline

I have to create a little program in C++, expecting a string in input and outputting its content in letters (How many As it's got, and so on).

I'm doing this by creating an integer array of 26 blocks, and confronting with a for cycle my string with the string "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" and the lower-case one. If a correspondence is found with index i, the i-th array block's value is incremented by one, and the for cycle is broken.

However, I have a little problem: if a character not present in the alphabet string is inserted (like a whitespace, or an apostrophe), it is counted as a correspondence for i=0 (letter A). However, if I include that character too in my alphabet string, and cycle through it with my for, the problem does not occur.

This is my .cc file (functions implementation)

```
#include "08.Count.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int chartoint (char a)  {
//Converts an alphabetic character to its corresponding position in the alphabet (as an integer)
    string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    string alphabet2 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for (int i=0; i<26; i++)

        if ((a==alphabet[i])||(a==alphabet2[i]))    {
        //check if the char corresponds to the upper-case OR lower-case i-th letter of the alphabet
            return i;
            //when we find a correspondence, we output the point at where we've found it
            break;
            //waste of time continuing cycling if the correspondence is already found
            }

}

void list (string word) {
//Outputs the alphabetic distribution of the input string
    int array[26];
    //array to store the correspondence data for each alphabet letter
    for (int i=0; i<26; i++)

        array[i]=0; //Initialize

    for (int i=0; word[i]!='\0'; i++)

        array[chartoint(word[i])]++;
        //chartoint(word[i]) outputs the position of the alphabet the i-th character of the string word corresponds. We increment the value of that position in the array by one
    string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    for (int i=0; i<26; i++)

        if (array[i]!=0) 

            cout << array[i] << "  " << alphabet [i] << ", ";
    //we output the distribution in letters, but only for the letters that are found at least one time
}
```

And this is my main program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "08.Count.h"

using namespace std;

int main() 

{

    string word;

    cout << "Insert phrase" << endl;

    getline(cin, word);
    //To avoid the input string being terminated by a whitespace
    cout << "The phrase " << word << " contains:" << endl;

    list (word);

    cout << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `chartoint` function there is only one `return` inside loop. There are no measures to handle when a character is not an alphabet. `So in that case the return value is undefined`(for you it is returned as 0)

So change the function `chartoint` as

```
int chartoint (char a)  {

string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
string alphabet2 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

for (int i=0; i<26; i++)

    if ((a==alphabet[i])||(a==alphabet2[i]))    {
         return i;
        }
 return -1; // <------ indicates a is not an alphabet
}
```

Change the function list as

```
void list (string word) {

int array[26],index;
for (int i=0; i<26; i++)
    array[i]=0; //Initialize

for (int i=0; word[i]!='\0'; i++)
{
  index = chartoint(word[i]); 
  if(index!=-1) // <--- Check returned index
    array[index]++;
} 
string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

for (int i=0; i<26; i++)
    if (array[i]!=0) 
        cout << array[i] << "  " << alphabet [i] << ", ";

}
```

So if returned `index` is not -1 increment the corresponding character count by 1. Else ignore it because it is not an alphabet.

Comment: What an idiot! I didn't think I was missing a return in case no correspondence was found. Thanks a lot! However, Shouldn't an else be placed before "return -1"? And I think is better if I make my array 27 cells long, and put an "else return 26", and leave my list function untouched, as it is a little simpler and lighter. This way, if the examined char isn't an alphabet, 26 is return, the 26th cell of my array gets a ++, but it is ignored in the print process.

Comment: @JeffreyLebowski `else` is not needed as `return -1` is out of loop(i.e. it is returned when no match is found) If it is inside loop then `-1` will be returned `when there is a mismatch at first position` .. Yes you can return 26. So just replace `return -1` with `return i` after loop.(because the value of `i` will be `26` at the end of the loop)

Comment: @JeffreyLebowski `-1`is a "standard" invalid return value. as -1 will never be a valid index into your array it is a good choice, better than 26. `26`is a magic number. it works here, but just because of your special case. If you add characters to your matching array you have to change the value. Furthermore everyone reading your code will wonder "why is 26 a special value?", whereas `-1`is an obvious invalid value.

Comment: Again, I failed to note that, thanks to `return`, an `else` is not needed, so the `break`. However, I'd prefer to use an acceptable value for my array's index, so I can avoid the control cycle before, because it either needs an additional variable or the whole `chartoint` function to be called one more time, increasing computational cost. In a tiny program like mine it's nothing, but in a more complex one with a lot of choices it might weight. With a comment I can explain the 26. Using i, I'd must add a `-fpermissive` flag while compiling because I'm outside the loop inside which i lives.

Comment: Yes you are right. In order not to use `-fpermissive` declare `i` before the loop

Comment: If you are familiar with `map` you can use it to find the character count. That will save you from writing a lot of code